# Text close together that's beside and underneath one another (pic included)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have included a picture of what I'm trying to do. I've tried quite a few things with no success. need to have the text in a row and more text in a row underneath it but when the screen shrinks the the one set of text needs to go under the other. I have attached a picture of what I'm trying to do[image]

```
<section id="international" class="international">

<div class="section-heading">
<h4 class="title wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s"> Available Internationally</h4>

<p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s">
<div class="para">

       Appropriate controllers and power cords are available for your country

</div>
</div>  
</section>     

<div class="row">
<div class="col-m-12 "> 
<p class="para">
                 Power Formats
</p>   

<div class="col-sm-4 ">    

<p class="para">
   Test
</p>   
<p class="para">
                 12V
</p> 
</div>  
<div class="col-sm-4 ">    

<p class="para">
```

test

12V

```
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="section-heading">
       <h6 class="title-int wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s"> Available Internationally</h6>



    <p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s">
        <div class="para-in">
         Appropriate controllers and power cords are available for your country
    </div>




<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<p class="para-inter">
  Power Formats
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-s-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 "></div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">

<p class="para-int">
    USA
</p>
<p class="para-int">
    110V
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1 ">

<p class="para-int">
    Europe
</p>
<p class="para-int">
    230V
</p>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-1 ">

<p class="para-int">
    Japan
</p>
<p class="para-int">
    100V
</p>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-1 ">

<p class="para-int">
    Australia
</p>
<p class="para-int">
    240V
</p>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-1 ">

<p class="para-int">
    UK
</p>
<p class="para-int">
    230V
</p>
</div>


<div class="col-s-2 "></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>  

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct HTML w/ Bootstrap structure for that.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/20/

HTML

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <p class="para">
      Power Formats
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-3 "></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">

      <p class="para">
        Test
      </p>
      <p class="para">
        12V
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">

      <p class="para">
        test
      </p>
      <p class="para">
        12V
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 "></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't want it to go vertical until the screen shrinks small.. I wanted it to be responsive basically... I was showing it in the image vertically just to give an understanding of how the text is associated together.. I think i should have communicated that. My apologies

Comment: @Classics07 did you try resizing the screen? It works just fine

Comment: now it's not centering below the other text - it's either far to the left or too far right.. I updated the question to include the new code

Comment: I think I figured it out by doing this: <div class="col-sm-11">
    <div class="col-s-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 "></div>